# Most supported audio format for webpage for Mobile devices?

Tags: html, audio, mobile-devices

I plan to use an `audio` element on a web page, which is going to be viewed only on mobile devices.

Where can I find information on which devices support which format? Would MP3 be supported on most devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MP3 is proprietary and requires payment to use. Check out some of the free codecs like `ogg`, `webm` or `ogm`. There is a wikipedia page on it for HTML5 that may be relevant.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio#Supported_audio_codecs